# How to bind in array format in mvvm type xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I am currently working on a xamarin project, and I am using the mvvm format.

There is a single button in the UI, and a new textbox is drawn whenever the button is pressed.

In the case of a single textbox, in xaml, you can pass the value to viewmodel.cs in the {binding text} method, but I am wondering if there is a way to pass multiple textboxes to one array of the viewmodel.

Comment: Use a list view, and add an item to the list every time the button is pressed. The list will also preserve the value of the text box.

Comment: Thks u'r advance!
i using now 'List<Textbox> textboxList = new List<TextBox>' , if set binding, 'textboxList[loopcnt].BindingContext = Bindingcontext as textViewModel'
is it?

Comment: Posted an answer below, please accept if it works for you! :)

Comment: Separate Model ,ViewModel and View , here you just need to modify the data in ViewModel  but not  place multiple  views inside a viewmodel , get a better understanding from  mvvm Pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Code, bind listview from a ViewModel something like this.

```
public class ViewModel
{
   private List<string> _TextBoxValues = new List<string>();
   public List<string> TextBoxValues
   {
     get
     { 
       return _TextBoxValues; 
     }
     set
     {
         _TextBoxValues = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxValues");
     }
   }
}
```

In the Markup XAML, bind a listview with TwoWay Binding

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxValues}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Entry Text={Binding} BindingMode="TwoWay"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

When you click on the button, call a function in the ViewModel:

```
public void IncrementTextBoxes()
{
   TextBoxValues.Add("");
}
```

This will automatically increment the textbox count, while preserving the values.

Enjoy!.